# Where can I find a specific version of Internet Explorer 11 to test against?

Tags: internet-explorer, web, internet-explorer-11

I have a webapp which is experiencing problems on a particular version of IE11 (11.0.10240 and 11.0.10230) at a customer site. Due to policy, they can not easily update or install another browser.

My supposedly representative test environment has IE 11.0.9600 and I am not able to update.

I have checked modern.ie and the VMs published by Microsoft. None of them have the correct version of IE and my webapp works on all of them.

I have Windows 7 and 10 VMs available.

Comment: 10240 is the build number for the RTM version of Windows 10, so it seems that IE 11 version is for Win10 RTM. 10230 might be a build of Win10 just before release?

Comment: Thank @PatrickSeymour. I did see that on Wiki, but unfortunately I can't seem to find a version of 10240 to test against. The IE testing Windows 10 vm from Microsoft comes with 11.0.14393

Comment: 9600 is Windows 7.  10240 is Windows 10 RTM;  You can test both within an vm and the  iso of the correct version

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound I am aware of this. I'm looking for a way to properly acquire this version, since no downloads seem available. I have a Windows 10 VM, but even removing Windows updates doesnt revert Internet Explorer to 10240

Comment: @Evan - Because those updates are still seperate.  Its not possible to get an earlier build of IE11 on Windows 10 though.  So you can't get IE 11.0.9600 on Windows 10.

Comment: I'm looking for 10240 on Windows 10. @Ramhound. The IE version from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/ For windows 10 stable is 11.0.14393

Comment: @Evan - Right;  Which is Version 1607, the current stable version of Windows 10.  If you want 11.0.10240 that would require a 10240 ISO of Windows 10 which is NOT patched.